# Django dynamic url redirecting to 404

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-database

I'm trying to create a dynamic URL pattern where there's an ID passed into the URL and used the retrieve a piece of information from the database.
Here's the definition of the pattern:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id/>', views.detail,name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/',views.results,name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/',views.vote,name='vote')
]
```

and here's the piece of code used to retrieve the information:

```py
def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Questions, pk = question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

the user seems to be redirected to a 404 page no matter what id is passed in the url.

this is my index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- head -->
<body>
    {% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{question.id}}/">{{ question.qtext }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the `index.html` file ? The error is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide your URL in the HTML document like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' question_id=1 %}">Get Detail</a>
```